# Python: How to replace a character in a XML file with a new node?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I want to replace all instances of semicolon ":" in my node below with a new node "<colon/>" as shown below.

I want this:

> <shortName>Trigger:Digital Edge:Source</shortName>

to become like this:

> <shortName>Trigger<colon/>Digital Edge<colon/>Source</shortName>

I have already tried using search and replace string, but when I get the output all the "< >" change to &lt and &gt . 
Can anyone please suggest any techniques to do this.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get the node text, split it by colon and add one by one while setting [`.tail`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) for every colon:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<body>
    <shortName>Trigger:Digital Edge:Source</shortName>
</body>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for element in tree.findall('shortName'):
    items = element.text.split(':')
    if not items:
        continue

    element.text = items[0]
    for item in items[1:]:
        colon = ET.Element('colon')
        colon.tail = item
        element.append(colon)

print ET.tostring(tree)
```

Prints:

```
<body>
    <shortName>Trigger<colon />Digital Edge<colon />Source</shortName>
</body>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you for the quick response. There was one more thing though. When I pretty print the XML, the <colon/> comes in a new line. I want the whole of the shortName to be one line as shown above. Is there any way to do this?